# VLOOKUP using AWK to append multiple values as new columns in CSV file

Tags: csv, unix, awk

I have two CSV files without headers that dont exceed 1 GB. For example:

**File1.csv** with 4 columns:

```
1,75.10,"1","1"
2,12.01,"0","4"
4,26.57,"1","1"
3,100.94,"1","4"
```

**File2.csv** with 4 columns:

```
1,"D",0,5
1,"F",0,5
1,"N",1,3
2,"D",1,8
2,"F",0,6
2,"N",3,0
4,"I",,5
4,"F",2,9
```

Wherever there is a match between column 1 of File2.csv and column 1 of File1.csv, I want to append the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns of File1.csv to File2.csv – to create **New.csv** that has 7 columns.

Expected output (**New.csv**):

```
1,"D",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
1,"F",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
1,"N",1,3,75.10,"1","1"
2,"D",1,8,12.01,"0","4"
2,"F",0,6,12.01,"0","4"
2,"N",3,0,12.01,"0","4"
4,"I",,5,26.57,"1","1"
4,"F",2,9,26.57,"1","1"
```

Explaining the concepts behind each step will be very helpful for me because I am self-taught so far.

I am extremely new to AWK, and am having trouble finding a solution so far. I would use Excel, but my file sizes are too large and I'd like to keep learning about AWK.

(Edited) Below is as far as I got, through trial/error, where I've appended only the 2nd column from File1.csv to the end of File2.csv. I do not understand how the ternary portion works, so I would really appreciate an explanation.

```bash
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0","(($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA")}' File1.csv File2.csv > New.csv
```

Comment: A good first question but never be worried to show (what you think should be) your best attempt to solve your problem. It's much easier for readers to understand where you are having trouble. Include your *wrong* output too. .... Work your way thru the [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and you'll have all of what you need (and more) to solve problems like this. Good luck.

Comment: Assuming your field 1 is consistently quoted; there are no embedded newlines in any fields; field 1 values are unique in file1.csv; file1.csv fits comfortably in memory; and both files have unix line-endings, then: `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR { k=$1; $1=""; m[k]=$0; next } $0=$0m[$1]' file1.csv file2.csv` You can use the tutorial linked above to find explanation

Comment: If `file1.csv` does not fit comfortably in memory, a more complicated approach will be needed, or a different tool.

Comment: My code also assumes your CSV files do not have header lines.

Comment: I edited my question above with some more details, thanks everyone! I got the chance to read through the tutorial, but my understanding is still limited at the moment.

@shellter I got as far as I could using the tutorial you posted and after scouring the internet for more examples. I'm comfortable extracting fields using awk while specifying patterns, but this new problem I've posted definitely exceeds my comfort zone.

Comment: `test ? truthy : falsy` is the ternary operator: result is `truthy` when `test` is true, and `falsy` if not. `($1 in a)` tests if `$1` is an index of array `a`

Comment: you can store multiple columns using the approach I gave (empty field 1, then store what's left) or explicitly. eg: `a[$1] = $2 FS $3 FS $4`. Then output `NA,NA,NA` instead of `NA`.

Comment: As above ... And you understand that `a[$1]=$2` stores the value in field `$2` in the `a` array, with a key/index of  the value in `$1`? Note how in this sample code, I can retrieve values of array keys and then perform operations on those values i.e. `awk 'END{arr["xyz"]=1 ; arr["abc"]=2 ; print arr["xyz"]+arr["abc"]}' /dev/null` (output `3`) ...  (The `END` & `/dev/null` code block/syntax are just one way to run test one-liners with static data in awk). Good luck.

Comment: While `awk` is easy to pick up, you won't get all the knowledge in one reading. Search for the original "The AWK programming Language" and look for section 1.8 "A handful of useful one-liners". I think that is the best quick intro around. Good luck.

Comment: @mollc : if you're trying to understand the ternary, I'd phrase it as  ::::::::: ::::::::: :::::::::: :::::::::::: ::::::::::`if-?-then-:-else`

Comment: THANK YOU @jhnc! I was able to explicitly store columns 3 and 4 from File1.csv using your tip and understand the (($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA") portion of the command now. My new.csv file produced the same output as your original/deleted answer. I don't love that my answer isn't as concise as your original one, but that's okay. It's better I just understand what I wrote for now.

@shellter thanks for the additional resource, I'll keep it handy as I learn. I realize now that I definitely need to teach myself more about associative arrays as I don't come from a coding background oof.

Comment: Your version also handles the case that file2.csv contains field1 that is not in file1.csv which mine doesn't, so is understandably longer

Comment: Unless `awk` is mandatory, in this specific case, `sort`and `join` would be much simpler (see my answer).

Comment: Is the first field in File1 always unique across that whole file? If not please include at least one case of duplicate $1 values within that file where it is also duplicated in File2. Can you ever have key (first field) values in File2 that don't exist in File1? If so please add at least one such case to your sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton 1st value in File1 is always unique. There will not be times where File2's 1st value is not in File1. If these cases you brought up become relevant, then should I create a new post on here?

Comment: Yes, in that case you'd ask a new question if you can't figure out how to adapt whatever answer you accept here to work for your new requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your files are large, if they are not sorted already, the best is to first sort them (the GNU `sort` utility is smart enough to sort large files on memory-limited computers). Once the files are sorted you can use `join` (output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
join -t, <(sort -nst, -k1,1 File2.csv) <(sort -nst, -k1,1 File1.csv)
-| 1,"D",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
-| 1,"F",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
-| 1,"N",1,3,75.10,"1","1"
-| 2,"D",1,8,12.01,"0","4"
-| 2,"F",0,6,12.01,"0","4"
-| 2,"N",3,0,12.01,"0","4"
-| 4,"I",,5,26.57,"1","1"
-| 4,"F",2,9,26.57,"1","1"
```

If you absolutely need `awk`, again once the files are sorted, you will be able to read them in parallel (`getline`) and avoid storing large amounts of data in memory. Example (tested with GNU `awk` and the `awk` that comes with macOS, output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
sort -nst, -k1,1 File1.csv > File1.sorted.csv
sort -nst, -k1,1 File2.csv | awk -v r=1 '
  {
    f2 = t2 = $0; sub(/,.*/, "", f2); sub(/[^,]*,/, ",", t2)
    while(r == 1 && f1 < f2 && (r = (getline < "File1.sorted.csv")) == 1) {
      f1 = t1 = $0; sub(/,.*/, "", f1); sub(/[^,]*,/, ",", t1)
    }
    print f2 t2 ((f1 == f2) ? t1 : "")
  }'
-| 1,"D",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
-| 1,"F",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
-| 1,"N",1,3,75.10,"1","1"
-| 2,"D",1,8,12.01,"0","4"
-| 2,"F",0,6,12.01,"0","4"
-| 2,"N",3,0,12.01,"0","4"
-| 4,"I",,5,26.57,"1","1"
-| 4,"F",2,9,26.57,"1","1"
```

- Read next line of sorted `File2.csv`, store the first field (before first comma) in `f2` and the rest of the line (from first comma) in `t2`.
- While `f1` (0 at initialization) is strictly less than `f2`, read the next line of sorted `File1.csv`. If the read is successful store the first field in `f1` and the rest of the line in `t1`.
- Print the current line of `File2.csv` and, if the 2 first fields match, append the tail of the line of `File1.csv` (`t1`).

Note: we store the `getline` result in variable `r` (initialized to 1) and skip subsequent calls if it is not equal to 1 to avoid reading past the end of file, which is inefficient.

Comment: gets a bit longwinded to handle unmatched lines: `join -t, -a1 -eNA -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(...) <(...)`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I wanted to use AWK as I'm somewhat familiar with the command. It's important that I understand every piece of the solution so I can keep growing and manipulate the solution for other scenarios. Although I do appreciate how concise the join and sort solution is, so I will review it! Thanks for the thorough explanation. I realized a bit late that I want to handle for any non-matches, as File1 1st values might not be in File2.

Comment: So, please edit your question and show clearly what you want to do in all relevant cases. Ideally you should provide input and output examples covering all these cases. Note that normally the `awk` script I suggest keeps non-matching File2 lines unmodified. If this is not the expected behavior please indicate the correct one in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}
```

Records in File1 have more than 2 fields.

I would write this:

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  FNR == NR {t=$0; sub(/^[^,]+,/, "", t); f1[$1] = t; next}
  !($1 in f1) {f1[$1] = "NA"}
  {print $0, f1[$1]}
' File{1,2}.csv
```

I have the `t` variable holding the whole record, then I remove the first field, leaving the variable holding all the other fields still joined with commas.

Comment: maybe arguably clearer as `FNR == NR {k=$1; sub(/^[^,]+,/, ""); f1[k] = $0; next}`

Answer (score 0):

Encouraging comments for improvements to my solution that I was able to find using tips in the comments so far. This also handles non-matches.

```bash
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2","$3","$4; next} {print $0","(($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA")}' File1.csv File2.csv > New.csv
```

Comment: Don't hard-code `","`s set and use OFS.

Comment: Thanks! I got this to work.

 awk -F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4; next} {print $0","(($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA")}' File1.csv File2.csv > New.csv

Comment: Use `print $0,(` rather than  `print $0","(`. Also when setting FS and OFS to the same value considering setting them at the same time to the same string `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` rather than separately as `-F "," 'BEGIN {OFS=","}` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

```
mawk 'FNR < NR ? ORS = "," __[+$_] RS : NF = _*(__[+$_] = $NF)' FS='^[^,]+,' \
 \
<( echo '1,75.10,"1","1"
         2,12.01,"0","4"                       
         4,26.57,"1","1"                       
         3,100.94,"1","4"' ) <( echo '

1,"D",0,5
1,"F",0,5
1,"N",1,3
2,"D",1,8
2,"F",0,6
2,"N",3,0   
4,"I",,5    
4,"F",2,9' )
```

---

```
1,"D",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
1,"F",0,5,75.10,"1","1"
1,"N",1,3,75.10,"1","1"
2,"D",1,8,12.01,"0","4"
2,"F",0,6,12.01,"0","4"
2,"N",3,0,12.01,"0","4"
4,"I",,5,26.57,"1","1"
4,"F",2,9,26.57,"1","1"
```